# Name of a cube with cube attached to each face?

Tags: geometry

Is there a name for the shape that results from gluing a cube to each face a cube? I can't come with a natural description for it, and google doesn't seem to give any results (the closest being [a depiction of a 7-point finite difference stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code#/media/File:3D_von_Neumann_Stencil_Model.svg)). See figure:

[image: cube with cubes attached]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you talking about a [Tessaract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract).

The figure is [Dali cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract#/media/File:8-cell_net.png) and it's a three-dimensional surface unfolding of a four-dimensional hypercube.

As a more familiar analogy you can take a three-dimensional cube and [open its surface on the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube#/media/File:Hexahedron_flat_color.svg).

Comment: I like the analogy. The Dali cross has an extra cube attached to the bottom, though. However, the tesseract link leads to the [polycube page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycube), which is exactly what I was looking for (I believe my shape is an instance of a "heptacube").