# Show you can tile 3D space with this structure: center cube with one cube attached to each face

Tags: geometry, tiling

This is problem 2.1 from THE BLACK BOOK OF PROBLEM SOLVING:
Define a Czech cube to be a center cube with one cube attached to each face. Prove that all of R3
can be tiled by Czech cubes.

[image]

Just 'greedily' stacking these structures together, it seems like you can extend them quite easily in different directions. But I am curious how one would write a mathematical proof as asked of by the question. Or is there an efficient way to argue about these problems more generally - works for more of these cubic complexes.

Comment: Reference : page 3 [here](http://davidaltizio.web.illinois.edu/NiceProblems.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As you ask for a "big view" of this type of question, I will say that it has to do with the mathematical side of cristallography. Though I am not at all in this domain, I have met some of its aspects while doing discrete geometry, a domain born around 50 years ago, but also by working on "geometry of numbers", a domain created by Minkowski around 1900.

Instead of a Minecraft-generated figure, I propose you a figure generated by a Matlab program (Fig. 1 below ; Matlab program at the bottom of this answer) with 8 "Czech cubes", one of them being colored in green. We will consider that they belong to lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Convention : each little cube will be coded by the coordinates of its lowest vertex (i.e., the vertex with the lowest coordinates in $x,y,z$).

It has taken me some time before understanding how the central cubes (featured in black in Fig. 1) of the "Czech cubes" had to be placed in a 3D "quincunx" ; an algebraic description is given in formula (1) below.

[image]

Fig. 1 : $\textit{The unit cell is depicted in red.}$ $\textit{$x$-axis is on the right.}$

[image]

Fig. 2 : $\textit{The unit cell with its 6 interior points with integer coordinates.}$

The 3D space can be filled by Czech cubes in 2 steps :

- The generation of the central ("black") cubes :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&n+2q\\y&=&2p+q\\z&=&2n+p+q\end{cases} \ \text{for any } \ n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}, \tag{1}$$

- followed, for every "black cube" with code $(x,y,z)$, of the generation of its $6$ lateral cubes :

$$(x,y,z) \ \ \to \ \ \begin{cases}(x,y,z-1)&\text{lower cube}\\
(x,y,z+1)&\text{upper cube}\\
(x-1,y,z)&\text{lateral cube at the same level}\\
(x,y-1,z)&\text{---}\\
(x+1,y,z)&\text{---}\\
(x,y+1,z)&\text{---}
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

In this way, each $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ is obtained once and only once.

Indeed, if (1) is written under the form :

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&2&1\\2&1&1\end{pmatrix}}_{M}\begin{pmatrix}n\\p\\q\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}$$

The determinant of $M$ being $-7 \ne 0$, one has the inverse relationship :

$$\begin{pmatrix}n\\p\\q\end{pmatrix}= \underbrace {\color{red}{\tfrac17}\begin{pmatrix}-1&-2& \ \ 4\\ -2& \ \ 3& \ \ 1\\ \ \ 4& \ \ 1&-2\end{pmatrix}}_{M^{-1}}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

A first heuristic remark is that, due to fraction $1/7$, a given cube coded by $(x,y,z)$ gives **integer values** for $(n,p,q)$ (i.e., will be a "black cube") in one case out of $7$ which is exactly what we want.

Now, the proof : it suffices to check what happens in the *unit cell* (cristallographic terminology) which is the parallelepiped (depicted in red) generated by the 3 columns of matrix $M$ ; indeed, the whole structure is generated by this unit cell by translations. More precisely, one must plainly have a check of the six points inside this unit cell (Fig. 2) and verify that each one is connected to one of the six cases listed in (2), i.e., each  one is one of the 6 lateral cubes of a "nearby" "Czech cube".  Checking this can be done in fact visualy (using for example the projections on the coordinate planes).

**Remark :** as almost always in cristallography-like issues, the "unit cell" could have been chosen differently.

The figure has been generated by the following Matlab program:

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
 % cube plotting
 X=[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1];
 Y=[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1];
 Z=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0];
 f=@(x,y,z,c,w)(plot3(x+X,y+Y,z+Z,'color',c,'linewidth',w));
 N=1;
 T=[]; % big array 3 x s containing the codes of all the cubes
 for n=0:N
    for p=0:N
       for q=0:N
          x=n+2q;y=2p+q;z=2n+p+q; % see eq. (1)
          % codes for the 7 cubes of the generic "Czech cube" 
          M=[x,x,x-1,x,x+1,x,x;
          y,y,y,y-1,y,y+1,y;
          z,z-1,z,z,z,z,z+1];
          T=[T,M]; % appending them in big array
        end
     end
 end;
 view(-70,10);
 % the green Czech cube
 for i=2:7
    f(T(1,i),T(2,i),T(3,i),'g',3);
 end;
 s=size(T,2); % number of codes stored in array T
 % plotting all little cubes :
 for k=1:s;
    f(T(1,k),T(2,k),T(3,k),'b',1);
 end
 % plotting all central (black) cubes, one among 7 :
 for k=1:7:s;
    f(T(1,k),T(2,k),T(3,k),'k',3);
 end
```

Comment: thanks, can't wait to see the proof

Comment: A remark : this 3D "cross" is known as a **6-neighborhood** in 3D image processing ; see for example fig. 14 page 41 of this [document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281183711_Filtering_of_thin_objects_applications_to_vascular_image_analysis)

Comment: I have spent a lot of hours on this proof. I am not perfectly satisfied with it, but it gives the main idea : checking the points that fall on the/a unit cell. You will also see that I have attempted to ameliorate the overall presentation (in particular the figure).

Comment: This is great. But I am not so sure which step in the proof or explanation shows that you can definitely translate the unit cell with the 6-neighborhoods still 'filling' each unit cell?

Comment: I am conscious that there is still a part of "handwaving" in my answer. Let me continue to attempt to convince you by another fact : To this (red) unit cell $\Sigma$ are "attached" 8 black squares. If you translate by a certain translation $\Sigma$ into $\Sigma'$ in such a way that $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$ share a common face, the black cubes associated to $\Sigma'$ are translated from the black cubes attached to $\Sigma$ ; this is why knowing what "happens" in $\Sigma$ is enough... in particular understanding to which "Czech cube" is attached each one of the 6 interior points.

Comment: But I am sure I can improve this answer and/or find pertinent references.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2665261/305862) is for example an interesting reference mentionning that the "Czech cube" (more exactly the Dali cross) is one possible 3D projection of the tesseract (4D cube) which, potentialy could give another proof of the "paving property".